# filter with prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, filter, prefetch

I want to know how I can filter my def to see only questions for the filtered patient.

I have try this:

```
def detail3(request, patient_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_id)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(patient=patient_id).prefetch_related('reply_set').all().order_by('pub_date')
    return render_to_response('PQR/detail3.html', {'questions_list': questions, 'patient': patient })
```

patient=patient_id => When I start my views with my template i have this result :

> "Cannot resolve keyword 'patient' into field."

I have no idea why this error is happening because when i try another solution with the same argument (patient=patient_id)I have no problem !

```
def detail2(request, patient_id):
    tab_replies = []
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_id)
    questions = Question.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')
    for question in questions:
        tab_replies.append(question.reply_set.filter(patient=patient_id))
        replies_per_question = zip(questions, tab_replies)    
    return render_to_response('PQR/index.html', {'questions_list': replies_per_question, 'patient': patient })
```

So what is the solution for filter my questions with patient_id with the method prefetch_related ?
Thanks you for you help !

This is my models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + ' [' + str(self.id) + ']'

    def listReply(self):
        replies = Reply.objects.filter(patient= self.id)
        return replies

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    reply_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.reply_text)
```

Comment: Can you attach the `Question` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to filter by a field in the `Question` model that does not exist:

```
Question.objects.filter(patient=patient_id)
```

patient is not a `Question` field and this is why you're getting this error.

In your `Reply` model, add a `related_name` property to the question field:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="replies")
```

Then you can query the list of questions with replies by a specific patient by doing:

```
Question.objects.filter(replies__patient=patient_id)
```

Comment: So how can i obtain the full list of questions and if applicable for my patient the relevant replies !

Comment: Attaching the Patient model would help. :)

Comment: I have replace by `Question.objects.filter(question_set__patient=patient_id)` and now i have this error : **Cannot resolve keyword 'question_set' into field.**

Comment: I have obtain  `questions = Question.objects.filter(question_set__patient=patient_id).prefetch_related('reply_set').all().order_by('pub_date')`

Comment: Did you have an idea ? :)

Comment: I have obtain `questions = Question.objects.filter(replies__patient=patient_id).prefetch_related('reply_set').all()` but this option can't be use with the method prefetch_related.  I have this error : **Cannot find 'reply_set' on Question object, 'reply_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()** Thanks you for your time !

Comment: Use replies instead of reply_set. I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve with the prefetch_related though.